# function from a base 32 number to an RGB Color (0-255,0-255,0-255) tuple

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have long base 32 number. 
I would like to map a sub string of it into an RGB color which means a tuple of 3 0 - 255 numbers (Alpha is always 255 for me).

I wonder what is the best way to do so.

I am looking for a way that will be uni-formal and as unique as it gets. I will prefer it to use as less chars possible.

5 chars of base 32 gives us 32^5 = 33,554,432 which is much bigger than (0-255,0-255,0-255) = 256^3 = 1,6777,216 So I believe 5 chars is enough to do so.

I've tried using range normalization but that is not good because I get real numbers which is not useful when talking about RGB pixels (need to be integers).

Comment: $x \mapsto 0$ ;P

Comment: Would converting that string of 5 five bit numbers to a single 25 bit dword, and then using the three lowest bytes of that work? The most significant bit of the last five bit number is thrown out because you have 25 bits and only need 24.